# JavaScript: Convert number to comma separated Array then back again

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
function indexNumber(number) {
    return Array.from(number.toString()).map(Number)
}

Input = 123
Output = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

I'm wanting to convert it back again. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: btw, you need not to map separately, just add `Number` as second parameter of `Array.from`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to join and convert string to number

```js
function digitsToNumber(digits) {
  return +digits.join("")
}

console.log(digitsToNumber([1, 2, 3]))
```